# Center Button Over Image in Responsive Div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Div contains a background image - provided at runtime (so can't use img as background), on top of the image is a button. First approach was to use absolute positioning to place button above image. This works until the page is resized and the div resizes.

http://jsfiddle.net/ubWuX/330/

First div is what I am going for, 2 and 3 show what happens after resize

Also the div image is optional so if none is given, div should should have a bg-color

```css
#img_container {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:gray;
}

.button {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:78px;
    right:40px;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
}
.resize {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="img_container">
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png"/>
     <button class="button"> click here </button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="resize" id="img_container">
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png"/>
    <button class="button"> click here </button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="resize" id="img_container">
    <button class="button"> click here </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the width of something you can use minus half the width with margin and position it in the middle like my example below and it will sit in the middle of the left and right of the page. This also works for top and bottom positioning, to get the object in the exact centre of the screen or area. Works for `position:absolute` like you have.

**This also works the same:**

```
.button{
position:absolute;
width:100px;
height:30px;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin: -15px 0px 0px -50px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ubWuX/332/)

```css
#img_container {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:gray;
}

.button {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:50%;
    right:50%;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
margin:0px -50px -15px 0px;
}
.resize {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="img_container">
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png"/>
     <button class="button"> click here </button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="resize" id="img_container">
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png"/>
    <button class="button"> click here </button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="resize" id="img_container">
    <button class="button"> click here </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this css

```
.button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

check >> http://jsfiddle.net/ubWuX/331/

```css
#img_container {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:gray;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.resize {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="img_container">
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png"/>
     <button class="button"> click here </button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="resize" id="img_container">
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png"/>
    <button class="button"> click here </button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="resize" id="img_container">
    <button class="button"> click here </button>
</div>
```